# Why does the connection counts of a long running query keeps increasing?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I am using this query to see the current connections:

```
select  loginame , nt_username, hostprocess, program_name, cmd, status, count(*) 'Connections count'
from master..sysprocesses
where spid > 50 and spid != @@spid
group by  loginame , nt_username, dbid, hostprocess, program_name, cmd, status
order by loginame, count(*) desc;
```

Whenever I run a query that takes long time (say, `count(1)` from a large table, takes 40+ seconds), the number of connections keeps increasing. As a result, the max
connection limit (default 100 for EF) is reached, and requests to my site get timed out. The exception message looks like this:

```
Exception Message: The underlying provider failed on Open.
InnerException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

Why is this happening?

For example, if I run the following query in the 
sql management studio:

```
select COUNT(1)
FROM tableA ss
INNER  JOIN tableB s
ON s.Id = ss.tableAId      
WHERE s.Time < '2015-10-01';
```

This is what I see running the previous query:

[image: Connections-count from mgmt studio]

Here it is showing 30 connections; but it keeps increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Using that query you are counting each parallel stream as a connection, if you just list them out without aggregating them you'll see a number of parallel query executions where the SPID is the same and ECID > 0. Use COUNT( DISTINCT spid ) or add AND ECID = 0 to the query.

Comment: But exceptions are being thrown stating that _all connections are used up_. I tried increasing the pool size to 250 (although ms recommends to keep it at the default, 100). Similar problem, just a bit later. Can you tell me, how to improve it?

Comment: Can you post the exact error messages you are getting. The parallel threads (ECID>0) do not count towards the connection limit. Also, what version (2008, 2012 etc... ) and edition (Express, Standard etc...) are you using?

Comment: Ok - so this isn't actually a SQL Server problem, it's a connection pool problem. Looks like your process fires up a connection (from the pool), executes a query but that query is taking a long time and as such ties the connection up, another request comes in, takes  another connection etc... until the connection pool is exhausted. You need to optimise the queries you are running - make sure indexing is in place etc.

Comment: My queries are optimized. Index/Stats are rebuilt/reorganized/updated every day. My site has a high traffic. 99.5% of the requests are simple inserts, but 1/2 request can be long-running (e.g. someone fetching a report which may take 2 to 20+ sec) which exhibit the same scenario like the one mentioned in the post. I observed that after a long running query, sum of connections are fixed at 100 and tiny requests timed out (unless I force kill the process). But normally sum of connections are around 25~45.

Comment: You need to establish why the application feels it necessary to keep creating connections, that's basically because the queries are taking too long. Might be a blocking problem -> run SELECT * FROM master..sysprocesses WHERE blocked > 0 and SPID <> Blocked to see blocking connections and the block chain. Use SQL Profiler to see how long statements are taking and optimise them. Rebuilding/reorg is pointless if you don't have suitable indexes in the first place!